# Using foreach() with a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a mySQL table which can be simplified down to something like this:

```
animal      breed
Cat         Persian
Cat         Siamese
Dog         Alsatian
Dog         Poodle
```

I want to display the information in this form:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="heading">Cat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="body">Persian</td>
<td class="body">Siamese</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="heading">Dog</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="body">Alsatian</td>
<td class="body">Poodle</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

So far, I have a query like this:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM aa_animal";
$result = mysql_query($query, $MySQL_extranet) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $resultarray[] = $row;
}
```

Then I think I am going to need a pair of nested foreach() loops, but it is the handling of the multi-dimensional array that gets me hopelessly lost.

```
foreach("unique_animal") {
  <tr>
    <td class-"heading">$animal</td>
  </tr>
  if ($animal=="unique_animal") {
    foreach("row") {
    <tr>
      <td class-"body">$breed</td>
    </tr>
  }
}
```

How do I manipulate $resultarray to get the right values for $animal, $breed, etc?

PROGRESS SO FAR

Justin's reply provided the solution to the problem as described above. However the real-life page has a lot more columns in the database table. Here is the code for a halfway file between the simple example I gave originally and the page I am trying to create.

```
<?php

$countryid='spain';

// MySQL query to select hotels and display all the hotel info
$query = "SELECT hid, hotel, pricefrom, place, region, country, picture, property, prop2, rooms, summary, lat, lng, zoomloc, breakfast, searchparam, specialoffer, biz_model, ta_rating, bc_rating FROM ex_hotel WHERE country LIKE '%$countryid%' AND showhide = 'show' ORDER BY orderr DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query, $MySQL_extranet) or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   if (isset($resultarray[$row['region']])) {
      $resultarray[$row['region']][] = $row['hotel'];
   }else{
      $resultarray[$row['region']] = array($row['hotel']);
   }
}
ksort($resultarray);
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="500" border="1" cellspacing=" 4" cellpadding="4">
<?php foreach($resultarray as $region => $hotel)
{
   echo '<tr><td colspan="2" style="background-color:#ddd">'.$region.'</td></tr>';

   foreach($hotel as $value) {
      echo '<tr><td width="250px">'.$value.'</td>';
   }
   foreach($hid as $value2) {
      echo '<td>'.$value2.'</td></tr>';
   }
}?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

All those values in the mySQL query need to be used in the table, but how do I get them?

Comment: First things first, I believe you should have a look at `foreach` syntax: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php.

Comment: Also you should consider ordering/grouping the results of your query, if you want to display all cats first, then all dogs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should group data when fetching

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   if (isset($resultarray[$row['animal']]))
      $resultarray[$row['animal']][] = $row['breed'];
   else
      $resultarray[$row['animal']] = array($row['breed']);
}
```

And then, display it

```
foreach($resultarray as $animal => $breed)
{
   echo '<tr><td class="heading">'.$animal.'</td></tr>';

   foreach($breed as $value)
      echo '<tr><td class="body">'.$value.'</td></tr>';
}
```

---

EDIT:
If you need more columns, what you have to do is storing full row instead of one item:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   if (isset($resultarray[$row['region']]))
      $resultarray[$row['region']][] = $row;
   else
      $resultarray[$row['region']] = array($row);
}
```

And then, you can also fetch those rows

```
foreach($resultarray as $region => $rows)
{
   echo '<tr><td class="heading">'.$region.'</td></tr>';

   // this way (display everything)
   foreach($rows as $row)
      foreach($row as $key => $value)
         echo '<tr><td class="body">'.$key.': '.$value.'</td></tr>';

   // or this way (if you want to display only specific item)
   foreach($rows as $row)
      echo '<tr><td class="body">Hotel: '.$row["hotel"].' / price: '.$row["pricefrom"].'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Amazing! I just copied and pasted Justin's code without even pausing to understand it, and it worked. Thanks, Justin. Now all I have to do is scale up the logic to work on my real-life page.

Comment: Inevitably, I have hit a problem in trying to scale-up. In reality there are about 10 or 15 columns in the table, not just the two. How do I handle them? Is it possible to do something like
foreach($resultarray as $animal => $breed, $legs, $fur) to create variables from the other columns?

Comment: Not like you said. It is hard to give you an answer on the fly without knowing utility of other columns and what you want to do with them

Comment: I'll update my original question with the test file as it currently stands.

Comment: It says here I should avoid comments like "thanks", but what else can I say. Huge thanks to Justin. Hopefully this will teach me enough about arrays to be able to apply them to other things in the future.